# Multisite issue

Tags: multisite, htaccess

Can anyone help me in this matter, I have a WordPress setup of my site on AWS Lightsail and now I am creating staging instance of this main site by WP-Multisite Concept.

I follow all steps mentioned in https://www.deciusac.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-using-multisite-apache/ and after adding related info in `wp-config.php` & `.htaccess` my site is showing error:

I added this below code in `wp-config.php` at appropriate place:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysitedomainname.io');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

And below code placed in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?krashak$ $1krashak/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I just created Network Site as subdirectory (http://mydomainname.io/development) but its not working at all, not even admin is login (http://mydomainname.io/development/wp-admin).

Please suggest me what should I do, its really very urgent for me, I need help.

Comment: I don't think you can nest multisite installs like that, and *your error message is missing from your question*. Keep in mind that this is a community site with unpaid users, so you shouldn't rely on it for urgent things

Comment: Also that's a very old tutorial you're following, it's much easier to do a multisite install via WP CLI, see the official codex